# Firebase Live Database Listener first-read/update distinction?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For iOS, using Swift, does Firebase provide an easy way to distinguish between the first read done on all the data in a database path when the listener comes online and every update after the initial read?

I could implement code to account for this, but it feels hacky. A flag or some value returned by Firebase indicating this would be convenient.

Comment: I see there's an answer but can you elaborate on the use case? Why do you need to distinguish between the first read and subsequent reads? Also, what kind of read are you using? .childAdded? .value? .observe or .observeSingleEvent? Those could change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database makes no distinction between the first event it fires for a listener and subsequent events. If you need this distinction, you'll have to maintain a flag in your own code.

Comment: Add as a feature? I think it would be better than having to search and compare locally to see if its an update or not, or pollute key:value pairs with flags...which grow as my data in a path grows. Also...I am lazy.

Comment: You can [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), but I honestly doubt that will be added any time soon. Either way, currently there is no built-in way to distinguish between initial reads and subsequent updates, which is what you asked.

Comment: Any way to bribe...uhum...encourage folks to add that feature sooner rather than later?

Comment: @ReverseFlow If your app receives an event, it's an update regardless of type. You would not need to do any searching as the key to the altered node (and the child data) is presented in the event. If it's .childAdded, you will know for certain a child was added. If it's .removed then you will know for certain a node was deleted.

Comment: I use both, added and removed child. And now I need the edit/update. On edit, The only way to determine if I already have the item is to search it locally, have a flag on per item on the database, or impose some abstraction that would indicate this state(the flag being an example...),  so polluting data or use cpu resources, either scales poorly...in that they scale at all resource usage wise. If instead, the event was like child added, I would know a priori to my local logic what to do with this new update.

Comment: @ReverseFlow The scaling is simple. When you receive an event, it will contains the snapshot of the modified node which includes a key. That data would match for example, what's in your datasource. Access by key and if it exists, update. A dictionary is handy for that task since it can be accessed directly. Similar you can test if it exists in an array as well.

Comment: I suppose that works. Its simpler than what I had in mind. I do need an extra data structure now. Current I do search a list and update as needed for one use case. I am concerned if I have enough users doing certain operations things will be laggy.